# Is it possible for a .NET Standard library to access .NET Core methods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

.NET Core has a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-2.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_) with the following signature:

```
.Replace(string old, string @new, StringComparison comp)
```

while .NET Standard only has this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netstandard-2.0).

```
.Replace(string old, string @new)
```

It feels odd to be able to use the .NET Core version of it in a web project, but not in a library project that is referenced.

I suspect the answer to my question is no, but want to be sure.

Comment: You can load the assembly and use reflection :). But you'd have to introduce an extension method on the .net core side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if it's only in .NET Core, you can't use it from .NET Standard.

> It feels odd to be able to use the .NET Core version of it in a web project, but not in a library project that is referenced.

Why does it feel odd? .NET Core is fundamentally a bigger API surface area than .NET Standard, so you should expect there to be things you can use from Core but not Standard.

There's nothing to stop you from making your library target .NET Core if you want - it just won't be compatible with (say) desktop .NET.

Comment: How does one target .NET Core from a library?  I only get .NET Standard options in the dropdown.  https://i.imgur.com/SAL5eu3.png